# Combining Similar If Statements In Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JS with similar if statements in order to have `Divs` side by side. As the topic title suggests, can these if statements be combined or made more efficient in any way?

**EDIT:** The purpose of this code is to make all Divs the same height.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container').each(function(){
        var firstDiv = $(this).find('.first');
        var secondDiv = $(this).find('.second');
        var thirdDiv = $(this).find('.third');
        var fourthDiv = $(this).find('.fourth');
        if(firstDiv.height() >= secondDiv.height()){
            secondDiv.css('height',firstDiv.height());
        } else {
            firstDiv.css('height',secondDiv.height());
        }
        if(secondDiv.height() >= thirdDiv.height()){
            thirdDiv.css('height',secondDiv.height());
        } else {
            secondDiv.css('height',thirdDiv.height());
        }
        if(thirdDiv.height() >= fourthDiv.height()){
            fourthDiv.css('height',thirdDiv.height());
        } else {
            thirdDiv.css('height',fourthDiv.height());
        }

    });
});
```

Test page: http://www.gloryhood.com/articles/ztest.html

Comment: Is your goal here to make all the divs the same height?

Comment: Shortening the code would be an option, using a loop and a single jQuery collection object, but your aim is unclear.

Comment: What `else` statement gets executed when none of the `if` statements are met? Also what Trueblue says. Your aim is not clear...

Comment: If you aim was to make all divs the maximum height of any, then the current code will not work anyway (unless the first div is the tallest).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, that's my intention, to make all of them the same height. I can see now that this code is contingent on the first div being tallest otherwise failing.

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer for you.

Comment: Rory McCrossan's answer is slightly shorter, so go with that one. I was aiming for readability. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the intention of the code is to equalise the heights of all the divs, you can negate the need for any `if` statements and use jQuery's `map()` to get all the heights, then use `Math.max` to get the tallest. Try this:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    var $divs = $('.first, .seconds, .third, .fourth', this);
    var heights = $divs.map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get();
    $divs.height(Math.max.apply(this, heights));
});
```

Note that the initial selector could be improved by adding a single common class to all the divs.

Comment: A bit trickier to wrap your head around (says more about my JS abilities than about your code) but brief and nice so +1.

Comment: It's pretty much the same as TrueBlueAussies solution, but he's using an `each` to manually create the array.

Comment: "...for finding the max height" you mean? Don't see him creating an array. I wasn't aware of the trick of using `apply()` to provide an array as an argument list, so to speak - seems useful!

Comment: Ya, you spelled it seconds instead of second, but other than that, this also works!

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg Ah, my bad. You're right he's not creating an array, he's using Math.max on each iteration. Either way, he got there first :)

Answer (score 3):

If your aim is to make all the heights the max height of any, the current code will not work (unless the first div is tallest).

Solution: check the heights for the max height first, then apply that height to them all.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.container').each(function () {
        var $divs = $('.blah', this);
        var height = 0;
        $divs.each(function(){
            height = Math.max($(this).height(), height);
        });
        $divs.css('height',height);
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/8hko6of7/1/

**Notes**

- I do not use your class names, but instead a common class on all the divs.

*If your aim was something else, please explain in more detail* :)

Comment: It may be better to clean up your fiddle :), see js part

Comment: @Mikey: Blame the OP. I just lifted all their code from the page link (I will reduce it) :)

Comment: Ow haha, I thought it were left overs from something you were doing.

Comment: That seems to work perfectly, thanks! And yes, all the same height was what I was going for, sorry for not being clear.